# android 2 async task run parellarly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

in my one of project i have to download about 20 to 25 json files data from server and have to unzip it so there are 2 process 1.download 2 unzip it.
i have used 2 async task. 1 for download and 2nd for unzip it..i started 2nd async from 1st post execute.
i want to do like.. if a file downloaded start 2nd async task to unzip that downloaded file... but i face first it download all the files and then starts unzip it... how i can overcome this?
i done

```
DownloadFileAsync myTask = new DownloadFileAsync();
        myTask.execute(params);
```

and in onPostExecute

```
fileProcessParams params = new fileProcessParams(zipFile, unzipLocation);
        process_FileAsync process_fileAsync = new process_FileAsync();

        process_fileAsync.execute(params);
```

and i am having 200mb+ data to download i am doing proper to use async task or i have to use any other? i also have to update UI while downloading this data.
thanks in advance

Comment: Well, does  `DownloadFileAsync` download all the files first?

Comment: yes @cricket_007

Comment: Then your onPostExecute can't start a parallel thread. It happens after everything is done in doInBackground. Did you try starting new threads immediately when you download only one file?

Comment: Why can't you do download and unzip in the same AsyncTask class with with different method implementation? Then it will be sequential as you want.

Comment: so you call one API 25 time for downloading JSON or all getting downloaded from single API?

Comment: @cricket_007 i dint get you

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit no i call from 25 different api and get 25 zip files

Comment: Check my Answer.. loop DownloadFileAsync 25 times using different API they all will execute parallel

Comment: how many Url's are there??

Comment: abt 25 @avinash

Comment: An Asynctask is a thread. Stop waiting for all the files to download. Please edit your question to add the doInBackground method

Comment: You can chain up all the Async Task's @Pragna

Comment: @cricket_007 in do in background code for download a file

Comment: @AvinashRoy can you plz give detail how?

Comment: check my answer i already answered @Pragna

Comment: Is this ur explicit requirement for doing it one by on or is there any scope for u to download all files at once and start unzipping one after another??

Comment: Again, give your code please

Comment: resolvedd problem using   myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run multiple `AsyncTask` in parallel, you may want to execute in a thread pool executor.

From

```
asyncTask.execute(params);
```

To

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

Note that `executeOnExecutor` was added in API 11.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DownloadFileAsync myTask = new DownloadFileAsync();
AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(myTask);
```

`AsyncTaskCompat` is Deprecated in API `26.0-alpha` tho. use it on your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
private class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
...
...
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
     //Do Ur Unzipping work
        new Task2().execute();//start unzipping Async Task
    }

}
```

Similarly, you'll have to put new Task3().execute(); in the onPostExecute() method of Task2's AsyncTask(after Unzipping),for the second file download and continue like this

Comment: what are u getting now??